# Saving a cardview programmatically even after closing the activity

Tags: android, cardview

I am very new to android and I am trying to make **CardView** by programmatically, I am using **Fragment**. By setting an `OnClick` on the button I am able to create cards in my layout. The issue is after closing the activity cards are not showing.

How can I save the cards, so after closing the activity cards should be there?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  getActivity().setTitle("Okhlee");
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hawker_jobs_fragment_layout, container, false);
  context = getContext();
  button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.hawker_job_add_card_view_button);
  button.setOnClickListener(this);
  relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.hawker_job_relative_layout);

  return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  createCardView();
}

/*Adding cardview programmatically function */
private void createCardView() {
  CardView addedCardView = new CardView(context);
  layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, height);
  addedCardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
  addedCardView.setPadding(10 ,10, 10, 10);
  addedCardView.setRadius(15);
  addedCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
  addedCardView.setMaxCardElevation(30);
  addedCardView.setMaxCardElevation(6);

  relativeLayout.addView(addedCardView);
}
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: what do you mean `after closing the activity`?

Comment: after closing the app, when i reopen the app i again need to add.

Comment: That is expected behaviour for Android App. Every time app is destroyed as onDestroy() called, all UI will be recreated. Read more [Activities](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

Comment: I know this, can you help me on saving this cards, so after closing this should not destroy.

Comment: you can use SharedPreferences like @tofira answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) in order to know whether you should display the card.

Here's a sample code using your original one -

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hawker_jobs_fragment_layout, container, false);
    context = getContext();
    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.hawker_job_add_card_view_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.hawker_job_relative_layout);

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean shouldDisplayCard = sharedPref.getBoolean("should_display_card", false);

    if(shouldDisplayCard)
        createCardView();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("should_display_card", true);
    editor.apply();

    createCardView();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this effort @tofira, But it seems not working same thing after closing the activity cards are not showing.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I've just tried this code inside a Fragment as well, and it seems to be working.

Comment: I am really sorry your code works like charm, i had forgot to use `shouldDisplayCard`